# $\forall :=\textbf{for every} \ x\in D_f\cap N^+_{\epsilon}(a) \Rightarrow := \textbf{implies that} \ f(a)=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **Clime** : let $f'(a +)=0$
>
> then $$ \exists  \  N^+_{\epsilon}(a) $$ such that :
> $$\forall :=\textbf{for every} \ x\in D_f\cap  N^+_{\epsilon}(a) \Rightarrow := \textbf{implies that} \ f(a)=f(x)$$

it is right ? how prove ?
please helpe me

Comment: I feel like your claim needs to depend on $\varepsilon$...

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist . I edited . it is right ?

Comment: Is $f: D_f \to \mathbb R$? And $D_f$ the domain of $f$? I assume $N_\varepsilon^+ (a)$ is an open ball around $a$. If so I don’t think this is true.

Comment: I can't even parse the claim. For all is defined as for every $x$ in $D_f \cap N_\epsilon^+(a)$ implies is defined as implies that $f(a)$ is equal to $f(x)$?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist 
$$f:D_f \to \mathbb{R} \\N_{\epsilon}^+(a):=\text{ right neighborhood of point a}$$

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your notation correctly, then the claim is not true. Here is one counter-example:

Let $f(x)=x^2$, with $D_f = \mathbb R$. Let $a=0$. Then $f^\prime (0+) = 0$, but $f(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks. 
Now let $f'(a+)=0$ then What result can be obtained in right neighborhood of point a ?

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't think you can say anything about the right neighbourhood of $a$ when $f^\prime (a+) = 0$. However, if, say $f^\prime (a+) > 0$ and $f\in C^1$ (or at least have that $f^\prime$ is right-continuous), then you do know that for some small enough right-neighbourhood, $f(x)>f(a)$, when $x\neq a$.

Comment: now let  $f'(a+)$ exists and $ \exists  \  N^+_{\epsilon}(a) $ such that :

$$f(a)=f(x) \ \forall x \in D_f \cap N_{\epsilon}^+(a)$$

then $$f'(a+)=0$$
it is right ?

Comment: It looks right. You should find that $f^\prime (x) = 0$ for all $x \in D_f \cap N_\varepsilon^+ (a) - \{a\}$. This implies that $f^\prime (a + ) = 0$. I think you might need $N_\varepsilon^+ (a) \subset D_f$, however.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: not now !!!!^_^